# Why I am not able to output or store the full list?

Tags: python, numpy, librosa

I am currently trying to sample an audio file, such that i can use the samples to train a neural network. The problem is that i am not able to view all the samples, or store them in a file such that I don't need to do the sampling everytime i test the program.

When I print it, or store it in a file, it stores it as...

```
[ -1.58969939e-04  -2.00387745e-04  -1.95918292e-05 ...,   2.24034284e-05
   3.28184578e-05   1.21092118e-04]
```

Which don't seem to make sense..  how do i get all the values?

I am using python library librosa to sample the audio file.

Here is the code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import librosa
import glob
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
import os
from matplotlib.pyplot import specgram


path_train =  "/home/k/kaldi-trunk/egs/start/s5/data/train"
path_test =  "/home/k/kaldi-trunk/egs/start/s5/data/test"
dnn_train = "/home/k/kaldi-trunk/dnn/train/"
dnn_test = "/home/k/kaldi-trunk/dnn/test/"
dnn = "/home/k/kaldi-trunk/dnn/"
path  = "/home/k/kaldi-trunk/egs/start/s5/data/"
train_filelist = path_train+"/wav_train.txt"
test_filelist = path_test+"/wav_test.txt"


def load_sound_files(file_paths):
    raw_sounds = []
    for fp in file_paths:
        X,sr = librosa.load(fp)
        raw_sounds.append(X)
    return raw_sounds

files_train_path = [dnn_train+f for f in listdir(dnn_train) if isfile(join(dnn_train, f))]
files_test_path = [dnn_test+f for f in listdir(dnn_test) if isfile(join(dnn_test, f))]

files_train_name = [f for f in listdir(dnn_train) if isfile(join(dnn_train, f))]
files_test_name = [f for f in listdir(dnn_test) if isfile(join(dnn_test, f))]


os.chdir(dnn_train)


train_data = load_sound_files(files_train_path)
print "Train done!"

test_data  = load_sound_files(files_test_path)
print "Test done!"
os.chdir(dnn)

#----------------------------------------------------------------------#
#----------------------------Main--------------------------------------#

print train_data[0]
```

What am I doing wrong? I could provide you access to the audio files I am sampling if that could be use full.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on your problem? What do you want to do exactly? Librosa returns you with a list of values. Does it contain the samples of all files or of just one? Do you want to have them seperated by file?

Comment: The output does not look as a list to me, rather is similar to numpy array. How do you save it?

Comment: Yes, you're correct. Nonetheless it would be interesting what J. Down actually expects. It could be that this numpy array contains all the sampled data and he's only supposed to slice it.

Comment: `files_train_path` is a list of paths to different audio files, `train_data` would therefore also have a list of numpy.arrays. I would like to view all the elements of for example the first entry  in the list, or even better store all the entries of the numpy.arrays in the list to a file, such that I could just load that instead of calling the function, when I have to use it...

Comment: found the solution `np.set_printoptions(threshold='nan')`